# Ember simple-auth 0.8.0 loses session after authenticating

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I just went from 0.6.7 to 0.8.0 in order to get the testing package, but now I can't log in to my app. 
I'm using a custom authorizer and authenticator.
The authentication appears to work fine, in that a session object is returned with the props set, e.g.:

`{
  "auth_token" : "QsWF31u1Tz4wUvymWQX7BBn9v1m4WzzEgZ5qj2uWdMa5k7rbH11FAPIglOnxHb3x",
  "account_id" : "b123456",
  "full_name" : "Bruce Wayne",
  "role" : "superhero"
}`

However, in the `authorize` function of my authorizer, `session.auth_token`, `session.account_id` and the rest are `undefined`.

The only change is the version bump, and I can't figure out what I need to do as no errors are sent out to the console, except for the one that says I'm not authorized to go to the route I tried to access (because of course the session didn't have the props, so the authorization failed).

Here is the [Gist of my authenticator and authorizer](https://gist.github.com/jdhines/57ab3bf3467bab399aec).

**Update**: while stepping through the code, I get to the check for `session.isAuthenticated` and it's `true`, so that's getting set, but none of the other session properties are "persisting" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything the authenticator resolves with from the `authenticate` method is now stored in `session.secure` so instead of `session.auth_token` you would now do `session.secure.auth_token`.

Comment: I *swear* I tried that at one point since I had seen some snippet that used that. Thanks Marco.